# Printing a specific Item in a python list

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I'm little bit new to the python and I just want to know how to print a single element in a list. 
as example below is simple list.

```
test_list = [['abc','2'],['cds','333']]
```

I want to know how do I get print only the "abc" value. using the

```
print test_list[0:1]
```

it will show as

```
[['abc', '2']]
```

Comment: You have a list of lists... So, you just add another index like ´print test_list[0][0]´.

Comment: Yes. it is working Thank you @ nostradamus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test_list` is a list that contains lists.

Python `list` allows random access, i.e. you can access any element you want, providing you know its positional index.

For instance, the first element on the list is `test_list[0]`, and the second is `test_list[1]`.

In the same manner, the last element is `test_list[-1]`, and the second-to-last element is `test_list[-2]`.

In your example, you want the first element of the first list, so you can do:

```py
first_list = test_list[0]
first_element = first_list[0]
print(first_element)
```

Or alternatively, you can get rid of all those temporary variables:

```py
print(test_list[0][0])
```

Comment: yep. it's working when i use as print(test_list[0][0]) thank you for the effort.